# Starting a new async function while the old one is still running

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord.py

The **all** function creates a list of stocks who have no available shares. It then runs **alert**, a looping function, to alert me when the the stock becomes available. I need to run all these **alert** loops simultaneously but **all** waits for the first stock to become available before starting the next loop.

I've tried using threading to create a thread for each stock but I cannot await a Thread.start()

```
async def all(self, ctx):
   stocks = requests.get(f'https://api.torn.com/torn/? 
   selections=stocks&key={api}').json()['stocks']
   zero = []
   acronymz = []
    for items in stocks:
        if stocks[items]['available_shares'] == 0:
            zero.append(items)
            acronymz.append(stocks[items]['acronym'])

    await ctx.send(f'Zero: {zero}')

    for acronyms in zero:
        print(acronyms)
        # Thread(target=alert, args=(ctx, acronyms)).start()
        await alert(ctx, acronyms)
        # await asyncio.sleep(0.5)


async def alert(ctx, items):
    stocks = requests.get(f'https://api.torn.com/torn/?selections=stocks&key={api}').json()['stocks'][items]
    if stocks['available_shares'] == 0:
        await ctx.send(f'I am now watching {stocks["acronym"]}. I will let you know when there are shares available!')
    while stocks['available_shares'] == 0:
        stocks = requests.get(f'https://api.torn.com/torn/?selections=stocks&key={api}').json()['stocks'][items]
        print(stocks)
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await ctx.send(f'There are {stocks["available_shares"]} in {stocks["acronym"]}')
```

stocks = https://pastebin.com/FhuR4d4R ["stocks"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can schedule tasks for the event loop without `await`ing them immediately.  Here's an example using [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather)

```
await asyncio.gather(*(alert(ctx, acronyms) for acronyms in zero))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you!